# Cause of a multithreading error in a MQTT application (Python)?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, mqtt

In my code I create threads, which `publish.single` multiple times on a MQTT connection. However this error is raised and I cannot understand or find its origin. The only time it mentions my code is with `line 75, in send_on_sensor`.

```
Exception in thread Thread-639:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//V3_multiTops/mt_GenPub.py", line 75, in send_on_sensor
    publish.single(topic, payload, hostname=hostname)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 223, in single
    protocol, transport)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 159, in multiple
    client.connect(hostname, port, keepalive)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

This is the mentioned code part. The thrown line 75 is the one with `time.sleep(delay)`. This method will be called on a new thread whenever a new set of data (as a queue of points) shall be sent.

```
def send_on_sensor(q, topic, delay):
    while q.empty is not True:
        payload = json.dumps(q.get())
        publish.single(topic, payload, hostname=hostname)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

I get the feeling I am doing something which is not "threadsafe"?! Also this issue occurs especially, when the `delay` is a short interval (< 1sec). From my output I can see that the next set of data (100 points) will start sending in a new thread before the first one has finished sending. I can fix that and also this error by increasing the time interval in between two sets of data. E.g. if I determine the delay between sets using this relation `set_delay = 400 * point_delay` I can safely use a `delay` of 0.1 secs. However the same relation won't work for smaller delays, so this solution really does not satisfy me.

What can I do about this issue? I really want to get my `delay` below 0.1 secs and be able to adjust it.

**EDIT**

this is the method which creates the threads:

```
def send_dataset(data, labels, secs=0):    
    qs = []
    for i in range(8):
        qs.append(queue.Queue())

    for value in data:
        msg = {
            "key":       value,
        }

        # c is set accordingly

        qs[c].put(msg)

    for q in qs:
        topic = sensors[qs.index(q)]
        t = threading.Thread(target=send_on_sensor, args=(q, topic, secs))
        t.start()
        time.sleep(secs)
```

and this is where I start all methods off

```
output_interval = 0.01

while True:

    X, y = give_dataset()

    send_dataset(X, y, output_interval)
    time.sleep(output_interval * 2000)
```

Comment: Publish all code please. I dont know if your publish.single create new client or not and so on...

Comment: @Martin I edited my question with those code bits. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you added extra code, it doesnt reveal much. However, I have an experience with similar thing happening to me. I was doing heavy threaded app with MQTT and its quite save. Not totally but it is.

The reason why you get error with lowering the delay is that you have ONE client. By publishing message (I cant be sure because I dont see your code) you connect, send message and **disconnect**!. Since you are threading this process, you most propably send one message(still in process) and you are about to publish new one in new thread. However the first thread is going to finish and disconnects the client. The new thread is trying to publish, but you cant, because previous thread disconnected you.

Solution:

**1) Dont disconnect the client upon publishing**

**2) Risky and you need more code:** For every publish, create new client but be sure to handle this correctly. That means: create client, publish and disconnect, again and again, but make sure you close the connections correctly and delete the clients so your you dont store dead clients

**3) solution to 2)** - try to make function that will do all - create client, connect and publish and dies after the the end. If you thread such function, I guess you will not have to take care of problems arising in solution 2

Update:

In case your problem is something else, I still think that its not because of threads itself, but because multiple threads are trying to control something that should be controlled only by one thread - like client object

**Update: template code**

be aware that its my old code and I dont use it anymore because my applications needs particular thread attitude and so on, so I rewrite this one for each application individually. But this one works like charm for not threaded apps and possible for threaded too. It can publish only with qos=0

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
# Define Variables
MQTT_BROKER = ""
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 5
MQTT_TOPIC = ""




class pub:
    def __init__(self,MQTT_BROKER,MQTT_PORT,MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL,MQTT_TOPIC,transport = ''):
        self.MQTT_TOPIC = MQTT_TOPIC
        self.MQTT_BROKER =MQTT_BROKER
        self.MQTT_PORT = MQTT_PORT
        self.MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL
        # Initiate MQTT Client
        if transport == 'websockets':
            self.mqttc = mqtt.Client(transport='websockets')

        else:
            self.mqttc = mqtt.Client()
        # Register Event Handlers
        self.mqttc.on_publish = self.on_publish
        self.mqttc.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.connect()

    # Define on_connect event Handler
    def on_connect(self,mosq, obj, rc):
            print("mqtt.thingstud.io")
    # Define on_publish event Handler
    def on_publish(self,client, userdata, mid):
            print("Message Published...")
    def publish(self,MQTT_MSG):
        MQTT_MSG = json.dumps(MQTT_MSG)

        # Publish message to MQTT Topic 
        self.mqttc.publish(self.MQTT_TOPIC,MQTT_MSG)



        # Disconnect from MQTT_Broker
    def connect(self):
        self.mqttc.connect(self.MQTT_BROKER, self.MQTT_PORT, self.MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL) 


    def disconnect(self):
        self.mqttc.disconnect()
p = pub(MQTT_BROKER,MQTT_PORT,MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL,MQTT_TOPIC)
p.publish('some messages')
p.publish('more messages')
```

Note that on object creation I connect automaticly, but I dont disconnect. That is something you have to do manually

I suggest you try to create as many **pub** objects as you have sensors and publish with them.

Comment: That really could be it. Indeed I do not handle the connect/disconnect process whilst  publishing. Also I did not know publishing through `publish.single` would require a client. At least I do not (consciously) create one. Is the `Client` not the instant at the receiving end?

Comment: I am just using the module imported through `import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
`

Comment: hmm. Interesting. I didnt know mqtt has this function. I usually construct publisher with import paho.mqtt as mqtt. Then mqtt.Client(....). But to answer you, it looks that with mqtt Publisher and Subsriber are quite the same. They use the same class -> mqtt.Client(). It propably hard to code it this way, but you have more controll over it. And since you need threads I advise you to create your own publisher. Or simply make as many clients as you have sensors and dont disconnects. I see now you have more sensors but one client, that you want to use for everyone in the same time

Comment: Also, I just realized. Consider QoS. If you have QoS = 1, your publisher client waits for confirmation(Connack) from broker/subscriber, so it can hang on. Thats very dangerous when using threads. That may also be cause - You send message and with the same client connect to different sensor. but the previous sensor is sending connack but your client is not connected anymore, so something raises connection refused

Comment: Thanks, I will look into creating a publisher using `import paho.mqtt.client` then. I have just never seen this done before. The QoS is 0 by default, I think.

Comment: That would be very nice :)